# Webform radio button sets common functionality

Tags: 7, webforms

I have 2 sets of radio buttons which have different data and because they are radios, you can only select a single option per set.

However, I am trying to achieve a setup which will allow only one selection between the 2 sets of radios.

**So, if I select an option in set#2, any previously selected option in set#1 will be deselected and vice-versa.**

Can anyone help with this?

*ps: I know JavaScript should fulfil this need but I am trying to find alternative solutions in case javascript is switched off and the functionality breaks.*

Comment: AFAIK javascript is the only option

Comment: vimalnath is right, there's no way to do this without javascript, your only option is to implement this as 1 set of radio buttons, instead of separating it to 2 and trying to force it to be 1 set.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK javascript is the only option and I do not see any help in the Drupal [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module

You could do it effectively in javascript/Jquery.

Another option as Beebee suggested you could force all the 4 radio buttons into a single set.

```
<div id="content">
 <input type=radio name="chooseme" value="1" />
 <input type=radio name="chooseme" value="2"/>
 <input type=radio name="chooseme" value="3"/>
 <input type=radio name="chooseme" value="4"/>
</div>
```

Now,user would be left to choose any one of the four radios.

Comment: using `hook_form_alter` and form api `#states` would be the option I'd take.